# Baggage recheck international to domestic transit at Vancouver YVR

Tags: transit, canada, vancouver, westjet

I'm flying Ho Chi Minh (Korean airline)- Korea (Korean airline) - Vancouver (**Westjet**)- Toronto. Same reservation ticket with Korean air.

Transit time at Vancouver is only 1h20.
Do I need to pick up luggage at Vancouver and recheckin ? I read that I also have to clear custom, and afraid that I don't have enough time for the next flight.

I arrive at terminal M, leaving for domestic flight to Toronto also at terminal M.
If I have to both clear custom and take out luggage, any tips on the path from those with experience, in order to speed up and hopefully I can catch the next flight in time ?

Appreciate your experience. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the time of week and day, 1h20 connection time can be tough at Vancouver, taking into account the possible delays of the flight, queues for immigration (depending on your immigration status and any trusted traveller membership), possible baggage collection wait time and security screening queues.

While Air Canada has implemented ITD process (direct baggage delivery to final domestic destination) at YVR, for the time being, you should assume most other airlines may require you to claim your baggage for rechecking in. although the process is relatively straightforward (you only need to put the baggage on another conveyor belt if the tags are printed through to the final destination), you may have to wait for your baggage to arrive on the carousel.

Being on the same reservation means that your subsequent connection is still the airline's responsibility to find you an alternative. Unfortunately Canadian flight networks have suffered rather significant cutbacks recently so you may have to wait more than a few hours for the next flight to Toronto, or if you are arriving quite late, to spend the night at Vancouver.